# Simple search of XDocument

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, xpath

Suppose I want to return the value that has the XPath "/Tier1/Tier2/Setting[Name=aUniqueName]/theValue"

I'm using XDocument so I can use linq, but is there short way to get this value with proper error checking? All I can think of is to get each tier, check each tier is not null, then proceed to the next tier and repeat - which seems a lot more effort than using a single line of XPath in XmlDocument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use XPath with `XDocument`. Use [`XPathSelectElements`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.xpathselectelements%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) method.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a LINQ query that will do it for you:

```
var query =
    from t2 in xd.Root.Elements("Tier2")
    from s in t2.Elements("Setting")
    where s.Attributes("Name").Any(a => a.Value == "aUniqueName")
    select s.Value;
```

This assumes your document structure looks like this:

```
<Tier1>
    <Tier2>
        <Setting Name="aUniqueName">theValue</Setting>
    </Tier2>
</Tier1>
```